# For some $\beta,\rho \in S_X$, $\beta$ is an $r$-cycle, then $\rho\circ\beta\circ\rho^{-1}$ is also an $r$-cycle?

Tags: finite-groups, proof-writing, permutations

Some facts that I know:

- If $\beta$ and $\rho$ are disjoint, then $\beta$ and $\rho^{-1}$ are disjoint.
- If $\beta$ and $\rho$ are disjoint, then it is easy to show the required.
- If $\beta$ and $\rho$ are almost disjoint, except for $1$ element, then I think it is still easy to show the required. (Let $x$ be the only element moved by $\beta$ and $\rho$. Let $\rho(y) = x$, that starts us off a cycle, with length $r$. If instead of $y$ we feed in any other element $z$, we know $\rho(z) = a$, and $a$ is fixed in $\beta$ by definition, so $\beta$ leaves $z$ unaffected but $\rho^{-1}(a) = z$, so we would just get $z$ back.Summarizing: if we feed $y$ in, we are started off on the cycle, otherwise, we are fixed.)
- For $\sigma,\tau\in S_X$, let $\sigma\sim\tau = \exists(\alpha \in S_X \text{ s.t. } \tau = \alpha\circ\sigma\circ\alpha^{-1})$; then, I have shown that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation

My questions:

- Overall/obvious question: **how do I neatly analyze cases where $\beta$ and $\rho$ are not disjoint, or almost disjoint?**
- Is the $\sim$ relation possibly useful, in that should I be considering the quotient of $S_X$ by $\sim$? It's not immediately obvious to me how studying the quotient would be interesting, which leads me to ask **when is constructing quotients useful?**
- We are on the cusp of learning about groups proper in class, so MAYBE I am not supposed to be using any group theory facts yet, but MAYBE I am?

I would prefer hints rather than outright help as I progress (but once we are done, I do not mind if the accepted answer presents a full solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you write $\beta=(a_1\,a_2\,\dots,a_r)$ and compute $\rho\beta\rho^{-1}$ on $\rho(a_1),\rho(a_2),\dots,\rho(a_r)$ (and of course the other values also).

Note: I just realized that the form of $\rho\beta\rho^{-1}$ is given in the wiki link you posted above, right below the definition of a cylce.

Comment: Can you please elaborate as I am not seeing how this helps to prove what the OP is asking. I too am trying to prove this.

Comment: $\rho\beta\rho^{-1}(\rho(a_1))=\rho\beta\rho^{-1}\rho(a_1)=\rho(\beta(a_1))=\rho(a_2)$...

Comment: But how does this help to prove the problem? I understand how that sequence of equalities you've given works but what relevance does it have for what we're trying to prove?

Answer (score 0):

Try an example with with r=3. Write it out fully (e.g. $\rho\beta\rho^{-1}\rho\beta\rho^{-1}\rho\beta\rho^{-1}$) and note that $\rho\rho^{-1}=1$.

Comment: What is your definition of an $r$-cycle? This is the one I am using: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group#Cycles

Comment: A cycle $f$ is of length of $r$ if $f^{r}=1$(the identity permutation).

Comment: Hmm. We seem to be talking about the same thing, so I am misunderstanding you. So when you picked $r = $, $\beta$ was NOT the $r$-cycle?

Comment: No, $\beta$ is the $3$ cycle I referred to. Then you can verify that $(\rho\beta\rho^{-1})^{3}=1$, and hence $\rho\beta\rho^{-1}$ is also a $3$ cycle, as required.

Comment: $(\rho\beta\rho^{-1})^3=1$ does NOT mean that it is a $3$-cycle.

Comment: Agreed, I should have mentioned that $r$ must be the smallest such integer above when defining cycle length.

Comment: That still doesn't make it. Is $(1,2,3)(4,5,6)$ a cycle to you?

Comment: Ah yes, apologies. The implication is the other way i.e. if $f$ is a cycle of length $r$ then $f^{r}=1$.